# Lookup entries by multiple keys

Tags: c#, sql, linq, expression, repository-pattern

**Edit**

To further clarify, in the example below, the expression tree gets built by using reflection to determine the name of the relevant property. Since I have "T" defined as a class generic and already restricted to a certain interface, I'm looking for a strongly typed approach. This should be possible IMO.

**Desired result** *pseudo*

```
public class RepositoryBase<TEntity, TKey> : IRepository<TEntity, TKey>
    where TEntity : IEntity<TKey>
{

    protected virtual ISpecification<TEntity> ByMultipleKeysSpecification(IEnumerable<TKey> keys)
    {
        return keys.Select(key =>
            Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(entity => key.Equals(entity.Id)))
            .Aggregate<Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>, ISpecification<TEntity>>(null,
                (current, lambda) => current == null ? new ExpressionSpecification<TEntity>(lambda) : current.Or(lambda)
            );      
    }

}
```

---

I'm looking for a way to create a specification that finds entities by multiple keys. I already found this example on the net:

```
keys.Select(key =>
                Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(
                    Expression.Equal(
                        Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, propInfo.Name),
                        Expression.Constant(key)
                    ), parameter
                )
            )
            .Aggregate<Expression<Func<T, bool>>, ISpecification<T>>(null,
                (current, lambda) => current == null ? new Specification<T>(lambda) : current.Or(lambda)
            );
```

This example comes close to what I need, however it evaluates the name of the *id* property at runtime using reflection since any type can be used as *T*. In my case, I restricted possible types to a custom interface (*IEntity*), so the *id*property is known at compile time. How can I refactor the example to fit my needs? I don't think it is necessary to <strike>create the expression at runtime</strike> evaluate the property at runtime.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking. If you don't need to create the expression at runtime, what is preventing you from just writing the expression as a normal lambda?

Comment: @SteveRuble Sorry. I clarified it a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not certain I understand what you're looking for, but if I've got it right all you need to do is cast your expression to the right type in the `Select` call. This'll tell the compiler to treat it like an expression at compile time so you don't need to build it at run time.

```
protected virtual ISpecification<TEntity> ByMultipleKeysSpecification(IEnumerable<TKey> keys) 
{
    return keys.Select(key => (Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>)(entity => key.Equals(entity.Id)))
        .Aggregate<Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>, ISpecification<TEntity>>(null,
            (current, lambda) => current == null ? new Specification<TEntity>(lambda) : current.Or(lambda)
        );
}
```